# Show SONAR results in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

The [SONAR plugin for Jenkins](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Hudson+and+Jenkins+Plugin) looks to run SONAR analysis on a repo. How do we display some summary of the results in Jenkins?  For example, a graph per build of critical and blocker violations.

[Analysis Collector](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Analysis+Collector+Plugin) looks to have a trend graph.  However, [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13329565/34935) advocates SONAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sonar provides it's own dashboard for analysis metrics and violations, separate to Jenkins. 
The time machine feature in Sonar allows you to look at the historical trend of your project's metrics.

Comment: Thanks. That's not what I want, but I believe it is the truth.

Comment: SONAR plugin for Jenkins should create link to SONAR project, so it is not big deal, as you can start from any server.